# Excel - Pricing Calculator - Adding Y+90 for every increment of x over a certain amount

Tags: excel, function, calculator, increment, price

I am trying to create a pricing calculator in excel with the following rules:

If value A1 is between 0-50 the price = 80

If value A1 is between 51-100 the price = 90

I managed this using the following function:

```
=IF(A1<51,80,IF(A1<101,90))
```

I am struggling with the final rule.

For every 50 A1 is above 100 add 8 to the price

So for example:

If A1 is 101-150, the price = 98

If A1 is 151-200, the price = 106

If A1 is 201-150, the price = 114

I hope this makes sense and I would greatly appreciate any help in creating this formula.

Thanks

Mason

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=IF(A1<=50,80,90+MAX(0,ROUNDUP((A1-100)/50,0))*8)
```

Comment: Nice idea using `MAX` here, I would have gone with `IF`, which is an uglier solution :)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much. Would of never got there myself.